# Looking for examples of product demonstrating real life application of Deferred callbacks (thread safe) system

Tags: thread-safety, deferred, asynccallback

I am looking for examples of product(s) demonstrating real life application of thread-safe Deferred callbacks system at higher levels i.e. other than OS level IO handling or event handling.
Any leads would by highly appreciated.

Thanks.

I tried to find the examples, but mostly found low-level applications.